# How to pass a string to child form?

Tags: c#, string, forms

Basically what I'm trying to do is I have a string on the main form that pulls its value from a textbox.

I then generate a modal version of a second form and want to have that string (or the main forms textbox1.text value) usable in the second form for processes.

Main Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;




namespace Tool{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public string hostname;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = hostname;

        }
     public void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string hostname = textBox1.Text;
            SiteForm frmsite = new SiteForm();
            frmsite.ShowDialog();


        }

    }
}
```

'
Child Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Tool
{
    public partial class SiteForm : Form
    {
        public string hostname {get; set; }
        public SiteForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = this.hostname;
        }


    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this? I know there has to be a simpler way, sorry I'm still a bit of a noob and am trying to teach myself C# as I go.

The result is when I click the label on the child form it is blank, because of this I am able to deduce that the string isn't passing between the two forms correctly.

Comment: I don't see where the string is passed between the forms at all, actually. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to pass it in the constructor of the Child form, for example:

```
private string _hostname = "";

...

public SiteForm(string hostname)
{
    _hostname = hostname;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you do `_hostname = hostname;` **after** `InitalizeComponent();`

Comment: @Bosak: No, you don't have to. If the code doesn't interact with the controls, either location is fine. If the code does interact with the controls, you will want to put the code after the InitializeComponent call.

Comment: are you Grea$eMonkey from Facepunch or another person? Sorry for offtopic

Comment: im not sure exactly what you mean by passing it in the constructor,

Comment: @user: Basically you are going to "send" the `string` from your Main form to your Child form.

Comment: im searching high and low to find a way to do that but the best i can come up with is the url http://www.colinmackay.net/tabid/58/Default.aspx, needless to say that just further confused the heck out of me.  is there any way that you can provide me with a visual example of how you would do it with my code? im a visual learner

Comment: figured it out finally.... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pass_data_between_forms.aspx, the constructor was easysauce when i figured out how to use it... thank you everyone for your prompt responses and assistance

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking into your child form's `Load` event and set the value of its `hostname` property in an event handler on your main form.

```
 public void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hostname = textBox1.Text;
        SiteForm frmsite = new SiteForm();
        frmsite.Load += new EventHandler(frmsite_Load);
        frmsite.ShowDialog();
    }

 public void frmsite_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       SiteForm frmsite = sender as SiteForm;
       frmsite.hostname = this.hostname;

 }
```